# AngularJS ng-bind-html with sanitize not working in 1.3.8

Tags: angularjs

I have this in my view:

```
<div contentEditable="true" ng-bind-html="message" style="clear:both;padding:10px;height:250px; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; resize: none; overflow-y: scroll;border:rgb(229,229,229) solid 1px;margin-bottom:30px"></div>
```

and in a controller function (controller uses ngSanitize and has $sce defined):

```
_message = message.replace(new RegExp("{"+property+"}", 'g'), '<font style="background-color:rgba(0,255,103,.2);">'+property+'</font>');
$scope.message = _message;
$scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.message);
console.log($scope.message);
```

but I get some weird error in angular:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at htmlParser (chrome-extension://fpcnkepdihaljlahfnikcfdjombihalb/js/nova.js:10049:17)
>       at $sanitize (chrome-extension://fpcnkepdihaljlahfnikcfdjombihalb/js/nova.js:9963:5)

...

If I remove `$sce.trustAsHtml()` and just use the un-sanitized version, it strips my attributes from the HTML in the message variable which were just added:

`<font style="color:red;"></font>` becomes `<font></font>` but it doesn't crash.

Any ideas? (Angular 1.3.8)

Comment: seems to work for me. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11221/)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to compile the new HTML that was being dynamically generated. I originally thought that angular would compile it for me, but it clearly wasn't doing this. Here is the directive and final view code I used that worked:

`app.directive("compileHtml", function($parse, $sce, $compile) {
     return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

```
        var expression = $sce.parseAsHtml(attributes.compileHtml);

        var getResult = function () {
            return expression(scope);
        };

        scope.$watch(getResult, function (newValue) {
            var linker = $compile(newValue);
            if (element[0].children.length > 0) {
                element.empty();
                element.append(linker(scope));
            }
            else {
                element.append(linker(scope));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

});`

and the view:

`<div contentEditable="true" compile-html="message" ng-bind-html="campaign.recipientMessage" style="clear:both;padding:10px;height:250px; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; resize: none; overflow-y: scroll;border:rgb(229,229,229) solid 1px;margin-bottom:30px; margin-left:10px;"></div>`

Anyone know why this needed to be done? This seems very hacky - Maybe there is a better way?